# mysqldump include "use db_name" statement with single table dump

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to use mysqldump to programmatically create exports of single tables for a system of exporting and importing tables from our production environment into local development environments.

I need the .sql file to include a "USE database_name" statement at the top. The production db name is different than our local db name (we prefix test_ on development). It is imperative I preserve the .sql dump files as they are used on docker container initialization.

I can achieve this by including the --databases database_name flag in the mysqldump command. The problem is, this dumps the entire database. I only want a single table.

Does anyone know if this is possible somehow - to dump a single table but also include the "USE data_basename" line?

Here's what I have in a bash script, so far - where $1 is the specific table name. This works, but I have to manually enter the "USE database_name" statement at the top of the generated .sql file.

```
mysqldump -h {host i.p.} -u {username} --password="{password}" db_name $1 > docker/local_mysql_db/files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/$1.sql
docker exec -i db_container_name mysql {test_db_name} < docker/local_mysql_db/files/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/$1.sql
```

Comment: is it important, that the mysql server is running? if not you can first mount all `table_dumps.sql` to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/$1.sql` of the container. When you start the container after that, it will automatically execute all SQL-Files in the Folder applying it to the selected Database, declared by the environment variable MYSQL_DATABASE.   ..... I am not sure if i understood you correctly.

Comment: Thanks, the key was adding that MYSQL_DATABASE env variable to my docker-compose config or docker run command... did the trick!